# Node.js - JSON response to request cut off

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've distilled my issue to some really basic functionality here. Basically, we're sending a request to a server (you can go ahead and c/p the URL and see the json document we get in response).

We get the response, we pipe it into a write stream and save it as a .json file - but the problem is that the file keeps being cut off. Is the .json file too large? Or am I missing something? Node.js newbie - massively appreciate any help I can get.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var url = 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/history/?type=https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/inventory/types/34/'

var request = require('request');

request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('34_sell.json'));
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working okay.

Comment: But if you compare the .json document to what you see at the url, you're missing like the last 2 months (almost) of data.

Comment: They both end with `"totalCount": 424`. I guess I didn't look beyond that.

Comment: The last entry in my .json file is "orderCount_str" :

Comment: "file keeps being cut off" is not enough of an error description. You should explain at which point it's being cutoff, maybe at a specific byte? Are you running into file size errors? Did you not get any errors when writing the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/history/?type=https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/inventory/types/34/';

request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('34_sell.json'));
```

Not an answer but this is the code I used. I'm using `request` version `2.74.0`. And node version `v5.4.1`.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @FelixKling I do not know. I probably should have put this in a gist or something and not made it an answer. But it works using those versions I mentioned.

Comment: But it still provides a working solution with the given versions of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a get request to the url and send the json as response and write an error handling statement like if err then throw err..console log and see the result..hope it works